# Merging string values in multiple libraries in android

Tags: android

Recently I found a strange behavior when merging a string value.

I have the following dependencies in my app's module.

`build.gradle` in my app's module:

```
dependencies {
    implementation project(':foo')
    devImplementation "com.bar:bar" // a dependency from maven in dev product flavor
}
```

`AndroidManifest.xml` in my app:

```
<application
        android:name=".MainApplication"
        android:allowBackup="false"
        android:icon="@mipmap/app_icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        tools:replace="android:icon,android:label,android:allowBackup">
</application>
```

`strings.xml` in `foo` project:

```xml
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">My app</string>
</resources>
```

`strings.xml` in the `com.bar:bar` project:

```
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">Bar</string>
</resources>
```

I expected my app's label to be "My app", however my app's name turns out to be "Bar" sometimes in my dev flavor. Which is surprising.

According to the following docs from https://developer.android.com/studio/write/add-resources#resource_merging and https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/android-library#Considerations:

> If there exist two or more matching versions of the same resource, then only one version is included in the final app. The build tools select which version to keep based on the following priority order (highest priority on the left):

> build variant > build type > product flavor > main source set > library dependencies

> The build tools merge resources from a library module with those of a dependent app module. If a given resource ID is defined in both modules, the resource from the app is used.
> If conflicts occur between multiple AAR libraries, then the resource from the library listed first in the dependencies list (toward the top of the dependencies block) is used.

I've configured `foo` module as the very first in the dependencies block, but the "Bar" value is still be taken as the final merging result.

What am I missing here? How to solve this problem? Thanks.